# Determine the type of casting at run time in a List

Tags: c#, list, polymorphism

I have taken a list. The type of list is Base class. Now using the help of inheritance and polymorphism I have added the child class to the list by using up casting.When I access the elements of the list at runtime I need to downcast it at runtime in order to access particular features like methods or properties of the child.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string Id;
}


class childOne : BaseClass
{
    public string Name;
}

class childTwo : BaseClass
{
    public string Name;
}

class Test {

    public List<BaseClass> mylist = new List<BaseClass>();

    public void AddMembers()
    {

        childOne child1 = new childOne();
        childTwo child2 = new childTwo();

        mylist.Add(child1);
        mylist.Add(child2);



    }


    public void GetChild()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        int num = random.Next(0, mylist.Count - 1);

        var child = mylist[num];


        //Find out the type of child ie. ChildOne or childTwo
        //At runtime and down cast it two child 
        //Like childOne ch1 = (childOne)child;
        //To use the property of child one or two .
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it might help you

```
var childTypeString = mylist[num].Gettype().Name;

if (childTypeString  == "child1")
//....

else if (childTypeString  == "child2")
//...
```

Comment: The scope should not be local to any block because I need to perform some operation where I have to access both child's property simultaneously.

Comment: I do not understand ! as I see in your code you just return ONE child instance. please upload the pseudo code of what you want to do exactly!

Comment: I just want to typecast them at runtime and access them over the code.Not inside any if block. Consider 
I can check like this also :
'child as/is ChildOne' or 'child as/is ChildTwo'
But it will not help me because It will restrict my code inside the block.

Comment: you cannot access the child type without knowing the explicitly type. it is possible to get the instance of the child class at runtime BUT you can just call the shared methods and properties, it means the method and properties which already defined at base class. if this help you I will upload the answer.

Comment: I know how to call the method or the properties of the base class.

Comment: Not properties of the base class, Consider your child1 and child2 both override the DO() method which is already defined in base class, you can access the child1.DO() or child2.DO at runtime by instance activator. but the DO() method should be defined in base class.